# MySQL - Storing a long list of items

Tags: mysql, list, set

I have some data which I'd like to store inside a table. This data is a list of items which have an `id` (string) and a property called `source`(string). The way I wanted to do it was to make a table `A` which has 2 columns: `source` (varchar) and `items` (set). Let's say each source has like 20 items, and there are a total of 200 items. If I wanted to do it this way, I wouldn't be able to do it using a SET because it has a limit of 64 values, so I wouldn't be able to specify all available options of items when creating the table.

So now that we're in context, I've come up with 2 options:

1. Make as many tables following the same structure as I need, each one having 64 values (T1: 1-64, T2: 65-128, etc) --I don't think it's a really good option, but it's an option nontheless.
2. Instead of using a set, make as many rows as items, being the columns `source`(varchar) and `id`(varchar) -- Another option that I'm not really fond of since I would need to create a lot of rows and whenever I need to make a request, it would probably need to go through the whole table. Still better than Option 1 though.

Is there any way of achieving this with a rather cleaner (and cheaper computationally talking) solution?
Thanks.

Comment: You mention MySQL, so presumably you're thinking of using a relational database. If so, then your options are limited to 1: normalisation.

Comment: *there are a total of 200 items. If I wanted to do it this way, I wouldn't be able to do it using a SET because it has a limit of 64 values, so I wouldn't be able to specify all available options of items when creating the table.* Use 4 columns of SET type in the table. Or use one BINARY(32) column.

Comment: @Akina That's actually something I didn't think about, and sounds good but the problem is that the number of items might grow and if it reaches 257, I'd need to manually create a columm and set up the values. Good approach though, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said items have a property `source`. But then you want to store the data as if the list of items is a property of each source?

This really sounds like you have a many-to-many relationship between items and sources. This is the typical solution to do that in a relational database:

```
CREATE TABLE items ( item_id INT PRIMARY KEY );

CREATE TABLE sources ( source_id INT PRIMARY KEY );

CREATE TABLE item_sources (
  item_id INT NOT NULL,
  source_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id, source_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (item_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES sources (source_id)
);
```

- Store one row in `item_sources` each time you assign an item to a source.
- You can have as many as you want.
- It's easy to add another, just by inserting a row.
- It's easy to remove one, by deleting a row.
- It's easy to fetch the items for a given source.
- It's easy to fetch the sources for a given item.
- It's easy to count them or sort them, or figure out which items are most popular, or do anything else you want.

You only asked how to *store* them, you didn't identify any queries you need to make. But lacking any information about specific queries, you should default to using normalized table structure like that above.

If you want to optimize for some specific query, you may choose to denormalize, but to do that you must have the specific query in mind. You can't choose which way to denormalize until you know the query you want to optimize.

Keep in mind that if you optimize for one type of query, this will come at the expense of other types of queries.

Normalization is the best way to remain flexible with respect to the types of queries you can run with reasonable efficiency.

Comment: I want to gather the items and sort them by `source`, as a colecction. I need to make a petition to an API with all the items (which have a property source), and I have to sort them out by source. Once I have all the lists, I need to update the table `items` column with all the items id. 

Pretty much it is a many-to-many but since I'm making petitions to an API, I didn't want to store a lot of data, hence Option 2 which is pretty much what you described, and it is what I'll end up doing. Thanks!!

Comment: You might like to use the [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in queries to return results with items per source.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful in order to retrieve data from the DB!